# How to understand if a variable consist in set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There is such example

$${A = \{1, 2, \{1\}, \{2, \varnothing\}\}}$$

Question is - if

$${2 \subseteq A}$$

as for me it is true, but actually it is false. I am trying to understand why?

Is there is some more examples to understand this?

Comment: A full answer depends on how you are defining $2$. For you is it the set $\{0,1\}$, or is it something that is not a set at all?

Comment: Notation might be confusing.  Distinguish between $2\in A$ and $2\subseteq A$.

Comment: In the definition of a set with a "listing" of its elements, the objects in the list are the elements; thus $2 \in A$ as well as $\{ 1 \} \in A$.

Comment: Subsets of $A$ are those sets whose elements are also elements of $A$. Thus $\{ 2 \} \subset A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2 \color{red}{\in} A$, but $2 \nsubseteq A.$

$2$ is an element, not a set in itself.

Comment: "2 is an element, not a set in itself." That's debatable: [Set-theoretic definition of natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut In this context it may be assumed so as the OP states that $2 \subseteq A$ is false, no?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut If it is defined in the manner you are suggesting, then the statement would surely be true, but since the OP is looking for justification of its falsity it’s probably just an element here.

Comment: That's correct. I missed the part where he says he knows it has to be false.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly - ${2 \nsubseteq A}$, not because of the number itself, I mean `2`, it could be any number - `4, 7, 888`, and still it will be `false`, but issue is this number is not a set, right? Like we can't compare number with a set, because ${\subset}$ sign compare set with set, not a number. Am I correct?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Yes, the $\subseteq$ operator is only valid on sets.